# jdk1.6 update 32 and JavaFX2.1 does work?

Tags: java, cross-platform, javafx-2, java-6, embedded-browser

i am trying to create a embedded browser using the JavaFX2.1 by using jdk1.6 update 32 however it looks like that all the programs are not working because of jdk1.6u32. but at the requirement its clearly mention that JavaFx2.1 will work with the jdk1.6update 32.

Does anybody knows what is the reason?

I am right now trying to run the sample programs which comes with javaFx2.1 and the below one

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm

while executing the above program with jkd1.6u32 and jdk1.7u4 program compiles and executes but doesn't display any page.
I saw the below error on the console:

```
Device "Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family" (\\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 6.14.10.5303
```

Comment: Can you please explain "not working". Compilation error? Runtime error?

Comment: i have updated the console warning and behaviour

Comment: It is just warning. It will not prevent you from developing unless you  are using advanced 3D graphic features of JavaFX. Try to code and run a simple "Helloworld" example. Also determine exactly which version is used by the app by putting these lines into `start()` method: `System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getVersion()); System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getReleaseMilestone()); System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());`. Append the results to your question as well.

Comment: thanks it started working I checked on my pc and found that it has javac=1.6u32 and jre=1.6u7. as soon as i fixed this everthing started working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better you install the 1.7 update 4 version of java because in that the java fx 2.1 is bundled with may be that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out it was a problem with version mismatch between my java compiler and java runtime env.

Comment: @Mac Wrong, if this was the solution to the problem then it does not belong in the question. It should be marked as the answer.

Comment: @madth3: you are, of course, completely correct. I must have had a bit of a vague-out for a minute there. Thanks!