# Device "Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family" (\\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed :

Tags: java, browser, embedded-resource, javafx-2, embedded-browser

i tried the below program to execute on my local machine..but it doesn't work.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm
i also tried the sample programs which comes with JavaFx2.1
I tried running the programs using jdk1.6u32 and jdk7u4.
for both the versions i am getting the below error

```
Device "Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family" (\\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 6.14.10.5303
```

After the above error program works fine but doesn't open any URL/web page.

Comment: dublicate of [jdk1.6 update 32 and JavaFX2.1 does work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10612591/682495)

Comment: yes, JavaFx2.1 can work with jdk1.6 update 32 as per the specs

Comment: I meant you are asking the same question again here..

Comment: can you run your app with "-Dprism.verbose=true" and separately with "-Dprism.order=j2d" and report output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working fine, i figured it out that it was a problem because of my java compiler and java runtime version mismatch.